# powershell script fails in Windows Jenkins server

Tags: powershell, jenkins, ssh

We have installed Jenkins(1.643) in windows machine. I have created a powershell script which will connect with my linux server.

```
Import-Module SSH-Sessions
New-SshSession -ComputerName vagrantvm -Username test -Password test@123
Invoke-SshCommand -ComputerName vagrantvm  -Command "cd /NFS_DATA/SP5/latest && echo test@123 | sudo -S ./test.sh /NFS_DATA/SP5/latest $App_Server"
```

This code works fine in PowerShell IDE and PowerShell terminal. But it fails in Jenkins job -> Execute Windows Powershell

Error Message :

> Import-Module : The specified module 'SSH-Sessions' was not loaded
>   because no valid module file was found in any module directory. At
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\VeoCanDev_6.1Deploy\workspace\autodeploy .ps1:9
>   char:22
>   +         Import-Module <<<<  SSH-Sessions
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SSH-Sessions:String) [Impo    rt-Module], FileNotFoundException
>
> New-SshSession <<<<  -ComputerName $dev_app1 -Username arthi_balakris hnan -Password Hybris@123
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-SshSession:String) [], Comm    andNotFoundException
>
> Invoke-SshCommand <<<<  -ComputerName $dev_app1  -Command "cd /NFS_DA TA/SP5/latest && echo Hybris@123 | sudo -S ./test.sh
>   /NFS_DATA/SP5/latest $App_ Server"
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-SshCommand:String) [], C    ommandNotFoundException

When I execute `Get-Module -ListAvailable` in PowerShell terminal on the Jenkins Server, output displayed is:

```
ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Manifest   AppLocker                 {}
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}
Manifest   SSH                       {}
Manifest   SSH-Sessions              {}
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack       {}
Manifest   WebAdministration         {}
Manifest   AutoItX                   {}
```

But when the same command is executed within a Jenkins job, the SSH modules are not listed:

```
ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands                          
---------- ----                      ----------------                          
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}                                        
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}                                        
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack       {}                                        
Manifest   WebAdministration         {}                                        
Manifest   AutoItX                   {}
```

Comment: well, did you install this module on jenkins?

Comment: powershell plugin installed in Jenkins. SSh-Session module installed in Jenkins Server using Powershell terminal.

Comment: well, under which user is jenkins running, did you install that module globally?

Comment: Jenkins is running as the Admin User. How to install that module globally

Comment: Take a look at the 'Where to Install Modules' section:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have downloaded the SSH-Session module and placed the folder in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

Comment: Issue Fixed. I have included $env:PSModulePath=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine") in my jenkins job and placed the SSH-Session in C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoItX